How can I pass custom data into an Incisor callback function with a button click?
I'm learning Incisor and I'm trying to understand how to pass custom data into my callback function when a button is clicked. I have a block of JSON data and a button. I am using a pressCallback and passing my data as a parameter. However, when I log the callback argument, I'm seeing a MouseEvent object instead of the data I passed in.
Here is my sample code:
class ProjectMain {

    init() {
        
        let data = {"id": 0, "email": "test@email.test", "active": true};

        this.button = new Button( nc.graphicAssets.WhiteBox, nc.mainScene, "MyButton" );
        this.button.addPressCallback( this, "myPressCallback", data );

        this.myPressCallback = function( data ) {
            console.log('callback:', data );
        }
    }
}

In this code, when I click the button, the callback function is triggered, but the console logs a MouseEvent object rather than the data object I passed in. How can I properly pass and access the custom data in the callback function?

Do you need to pass it?  The variable data should be in scope when myPressCallback runs without passing it.

Yes. You're right.  In this contrived example, I don't need to actually pass the parameter.  But I'm still confused as to why the parameter to the callback is a MouseEvent instead of my data object.

Try this.myPressCallback = function( browserEvent, camera, data ) { - this pattern is covered in the addPressCallback docs for the third parameter.
